# Поиск по параметру

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Подскажите, как можно реализовать поиск по параметру? Например, если пользователь ввел только имя, то искало по имени, если он выбрал город, то к запросу поиска добавлялся и город. Подскажите, как можно сделать часть там, где идет выбор: город ввел, значит, ищет ещё и по городу, не ввел, значит, ищут только по имени, ввел возраст, ищет по городу, имени и возрасту, не ввел... ну и тд. Есть ли какой-нибудь туториал, подскажите, пожалуйста?Хочется разобрать и сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот почитай тему там несколько вариантов решения данной задачи.

[Организация поиска в БД по параметрам введенным в форме](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread227475.html)

```
<?
 // Создаем класс
$select = new Zend_Db_Table;
// Cоздаем SQL, тут SELECT * FROM table_name ...
$query  = $this->getAdapter()->select()->from('table_name', '*');

if (isset($POST['что угодно'])) {
    $query->where('что угодно = ?', $POST['что угодно']); // И так хоть сто раз
}

$result = $select->fetchAll($query);
?>
```

Comment: А как можно, чтобы запрос постоянно передавался в БД? Тут пример обработки, а как передачу реализовать постоянную?